# Translate xml content using web service API from Ektron CMS400.Net

Tags: web-services, api, translate, ektron

First of all: I'm on Ektron CMS v8.1

I'm having a problem with dynamicly adding translated content to the cms via the Webservice API. I can perfectly add xml content by using the following object and method:

ContentSoapClient csc = new ContentSoapClient("ContentSoap");
csc.AddContent3(...);

I specify a language and the xml content gets inserted. But now I want to add a translated version of the xml to the cms. So I want it to have the same contentId!

Anyone has an idea on this? The only method in the csc object that recieves a contentId is 'csc.AddContent2(..)' But that doesn't import anything and just gives me an error saying my xml is incorrect. While my xml is correct..I checked it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer..

Ektron apparantly uses alot of asmx files and I only checked the "/workarea/webservices/WebServiceAPI/Content/Content.asmx" webservice. I found the method 'AddTranslatedXMLContent()' I need in the "/Workarea/webservices/ContentWS.asmx" webservice.

I wish they just cleaned up their API... Would save us a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

*Firstly, I haven't used the ContentSoapClient class and can't find any documentation on it.*

Ektron often takes a language id when you create the API object. See if the ContentSoapClient contructor can take a Language Id.

Comment: Documentation is always lacking when using Ektron API... I'm use to it by now. I could indeed provide a language id. But it would just create new content in another language. And I needed to translate the content. I found the solution and attached it below. Thanks anyway.